# Downloadable font rejected by sanitizer

Tags: nginx

I have problems with a font (font awesome). I have searched for a fix and what I found that causes the problem is the version query `('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0')` but in my case that does't fix the problem.

I have noticed that the problem comes from the `nginx`'s conf file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

If I remove the `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;` line the font loads just fine.

Here is what firefox says:

> downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1) source: http://example.com/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2

And here is what chrome says:

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://example.com/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
>   (index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Comment: I suspect if you go to `http://example.com/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2` you will see HTML, as you have rewritten every URL on your site to it...

Comment: Everything loads like this `http://example.com/assets/font-awesome/fonts/assets/css/normalize.css` instead of `http://example.com/assets/css/normalize.css`. So I guess that rewrite line is not good.

Comment: OK? That has nothing to do with what I said. What happens if you go to `http://example.com/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-web‌​font.woff2` in the browser?

Comment: it loads the index.php my website is discord.sl

Comment: OK, so your browser is looking for a font file, and it's getting `index.php` instead. See the problem?

Comment: well i`m not familiar with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added the folowing in my nginx conf and is working

`location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}`

But I still don't belive it was because of this.

Comment: It *was* because of this. Fixing your code so the `try_files` works without the `rewrite` would be a better approach (as it'll prevent future issues), but this'll at least fix your problems with webfonts.

Answer (score 0):

For those lost souls of you that still got "Downloadable font rejected by sanitizer" while hosting fonts on a nginx server. I checked my nginx logs /var/log/nginx/error.log, guess what: wrong permissions to fonts folder *face-palm*

```
...."/var/www/example/public/static/fonts/fontname.woff" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).